# partial_sum() position of previous

Tags: c++, pointers, position, recurrence

Using partial_sum(), I am trying to get the position from previous during the recurrence. I don't understand the result. I was expecting to get :

```
recurrence i=0
recurrence i=1
...
```

As the recurrence unfolds. But I am getting :

```
recurrence i=-48115006
recurrence i=-48115006
...
```

What am doing wrong ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        const int n=15;
        vector<vector<int> > vv(n+1);
        vv[0]={42};

        auto next=[&](const vector<int>& previous, const vector<int>&){
                const int i = &previous - &vv[0];
                printf("recurrence i=%d\n", i);
                fflush(stdout);
                vector<int> v;
                return v;
        };

        partial_sum(vv.begin(), vv.end(), vv.begin(), next);
}
```

Comment: First of all, why use the unsafe `printf` function in a C++ program? Secondly, why return an empty vector from the lambda function?

Comment: Did you meant to use the second parameter of your lambda, instead of the first?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, `partial_sum` does need the lambda to return something that work with the 3rd parameter. Better question, why all these, instead of `iota` or even just a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation for `partial_sum` that you are using is probably similar to the one described in [cppreference, Possible implementation, Second version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum):

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation>
constexpr // since C++20
OutputIt partial_sum(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
                     OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation op)
{
    if (first == last)
        return d_first;
 
    typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type sum = *first;
    *d_first = sum;
 
    while (++first != last)
    {
        sum = op(std::move(sum), *first); // std::move since C++20
        *++d_first = sum;
    }
 
    return ++d_first;
}
```

That being the case, the first argument that `partial_sum` passes to `op` (the binary operation, `next` in your code) is fix: it's a reference to an accumulator. It is the second argument the one that varies: it's a reference to the current element in each iteration (starting at the second element). But, in your example, you don't use this second argument to set `i`. Instead, you always use `&vv[0]`, which is also a fix value (unless `vv` changes in size, which is not the case). So it's expected that you are always printing the same value: the difference of two fix addresses.

You can see it working [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MsxercsqY) with some more debugging output.